# Converter classe em genérica

Tags: java, arraylist, genéricos

Preciso converter a classe do código abaixo em uma implementação genérica usando um *ArrayList*.

Alguém pode sugerir uma melhor forma de fazer isso?

**Código:**

```
public class ArrayStack { 

    private int maxsize; Retirar essas 2 linhas…
    private int top; 
    private int[] items; 

    public ArrayStack(int maxsize) { 
    if (maxsize <= 0) 
                     throw new ArrayStackException( 
    "Stack size must be positive"); 
    items = new int[maxsize]; 
    this.maxsize = maxsize; 
    top = 0; 
    } 

    public void push(int item) { 
    if (top == items.length) 
        throw new ArrayStackException("Overflow Error"); 
    items[top] = item; 
    top++; 
    } 

    public int pop() { 
    if (isEmpty()) 
        throw new ArrayStackException("Underflow Error"); 
    return items[--top]; 
    } 

    public boolean isEmpty() { 
     return (top == 0); 
    } 

    public static class ArrayStackException extends RuntimeException { 
     public ArrayStackException(String message) { 
         super(message); 
     } 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack(3); 
    stack.push(1); 
    stack.push(2); 
    stack.push(3); 
    //stack.push(4); //overflow error 
    System.out.println(stack.pop()); 
    System.out.println(stack.pop()); 
    System.out.println(stack.pop()); 

    } 

}
```

Comment: Tem mais de uma forma, além de substituir o tipo "int" pelo tipo genérico?

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução seria a seguinte:

```
public class ArrayStack { 
    private ArrayList <Object> stack;


    public ArrayStack() { 
        stack = new ArrayList <> ();
    } 

    public void push(Object item) { 
        stack.add(item);
    } 

    public Object pop() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
                return stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
        }
        throw new ArrayStackException("Underflow Error"); 
    } 

    public boolean isEmpty() { 
        return (stack.isEmpty());
    } 

    public static class ArrayStackException extends RuntimeException { 
        public ArrayStackException(String message) { 
            super(message); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack(); 

        stack.push(1); 
        stack.push(2); 
        stack.push(3); 

        System.out.println(stack.pop()); 
        System.out.println(stack.pop()); 
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    } 
}
```

Com o uso de um ArrayList, se tornam desnecessárias várias implementações presentes no código original, pois o ArrayList é um vetor dinâmico (são adicionadas a ele posições conforme a demanda, e não é necessário definir seu tamanho previamente).

Assim, adicionar itens à pilha fica bem mais fácil, não sendo mais necessário verificar se excedeu o tamanho máximo:

```
public void push(Object item) { 
    stack.add(item);
}
```

A definição do tipo do Array é o ponto principal: declarando-o como um vetor de Object, permitimos que sejam adicionados objetos de qualquer tipo, pois **todas as classes estendem Object**, ou seja, são suas filhas.

```
private ArrayList <Object> stack;
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução seria [parametrizar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) sua classe ArrayStack, e assim você evita fazer cast do objeto no main.

```
public class ArrayStack <E> { 
      private List <E> stack;

      public ArrayStack() { 
          this.stack = new ArrayList<E>();
      } 

      public void push(E item) { 
          stack.add(item);
      } 

      public E pop() {
          if (!isEmpty()) {
                  return stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
          }
          throw new ArrayStackException("Underflow Error"); 
      } 

      public boolean isEmpty() { 
          return (stack.isEmpty());
      } 

      public static class ArrayStackException extends RuntimeException { 
          public ArrayStackException(String message) { 
              super(message); 
          } 
      } 

      public static void main(String[] args) { 
          ArrayStack<String> stack = new ArrayStack<String>(); 

          stack.push("hello"); 
          stack.push("world"); 

          System.out.println(stack.pop()); 
          System.out.println(stack.pop()); 
          System.out.println(stack.pop());
      } 
  }
```